# Why do I keep getting class not found?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I'm using peersim from Eclipse, where it's sufficient to use these 3 libraries:

```
/home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/djep-1.0.0.jar
/home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/peersim-1.0.5.jar
/home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/jep-2.3.0.jar
```

And execute the main class `peersim.Simulator`.

However, now I want to execute it from command line (first time for me using java from command line). I tried with:

```
java -cp /home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/peersim-1.0.5.jar peersim.Simulator
```

But of course I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lsmp/djep/groupJep/GroupI
    at peersim.config.Configuration.setConfig(Configuration.java:319)
    at peersim.Simulator.main(Simulator.java:154)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lsmp.djep.groupJep.GroupI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

So reading around I tried:

```
java -cp /home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/*.jar:. peersim.Simulator
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class peersim.Simulator
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not give your jar file a manifest which has its own appropriate classpath statement within it?

Comment: You can't use the `*` wildcard in a classpath. Add all three jars explicitly.

Comment: @Henry as of Java 6 you can

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis no, not using that syntax. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#A1100762

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error by myself:

```
java -cp /home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/*: peersim.Simulator
```

Instead of:

```
java -cp /home/luca/peersim-1.0.5/*.jar:. peersim.Simulator
```

Solved the problem

Comment: As shown in the duplicate that I flagged.